# $(1-t)\int_0^t \frac{1}{1-s}\,dB_s\overset{d}{=} B_t-tB_1$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, brownian-bridge

Let $0<t<1$.
I want to show that
$$
(1-t)\int_0^t\frac{1}{1-s}\,dB_s\overset{d}{=}B_t-tB_1.
$$

I tried using Ito's formula for a standard process.
That is for $f(t,x):=(1-t)x$, denoting $X_t:=\int_0^t\frac{1}{1-s}\,dB_s$, we have $f\in C^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R})$, so
$$
\begin{split}
            (1-t)X_t = f(t,X_t)
            &= f(0,0)+\int_0^t\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(s,X_s)\,dX_s\\
            &\qquad + \int_0^t\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\left( s,X_s \right)\,ds + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(s,X_s)\frac{1}{(1-s)^2}\,ds\\
            &= \int_0^t \frac{1-s}{1-s}\,dB_s-\int_0^t X_s\,ds\\
&= B_t - \int_0^tX_s\,ds.
        \end{split}
$$
This is where I'm stuck.
I think I need to show that the right-hand side has a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $t(1-t)$ but I don't know how to proceed.
I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Since both sides define centered gaussian processes on $[0, 1]$, it suffices to check that the covariance structure of both sides coincide. You can use the 
Itô isometry for computing the covariance structure of the left-hand side.

Comment: Thank you! The key to this problem is that $\int_0^t f(s)\,dBs$ defines a centered Gaussian process for $f\in C([0,t]). This was not proved in the class I'm taking when I started doing this problem.